# Concatinating multiple collection of List<T> with mixed Types to Object?

Tags: c#, linq, object, casting

Given a variable number of List's of varying Type, i've come up with a frankenstein-worthy approach (`method2`) of concatenating them into a single collection, of type `object`.

Am I being a bit thick or is the below code more or less necessary?

```
object[] foo()
{
    var a = new List<string>() { "hello" };//type 1
    var b = new List<Uri>() { new Uri("http://test") };//type 2

    //combined
    IEnumerable<object> method2 = new object[]{a, b}.Select(x=>((IEnumerable)x).Cast<object>()).SelectMany(y=>y);

    var returnable = method2.ToArray();
    bool success = (returnable[0] is string);
    return returnable.ToArray();
}
```

I'm aware that its not possible to cast a `List<string>` to a `List<object>` as they are fundamentally different types, but thought the above was a bit extreme.

Comment: You could cast `a` and `b` individually, then `Union` the result? Or return an array of `dynamic` objects instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
object[] result = a.Cast<object>().Concat(b.Cast<object>()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually, it's as simple as this:

```
var result = a.Concat<object>(b);
```

Normally, the type parameters of LINQ methods are inferred as the most specific type they are called on (in this case, `string`), but there is nothing stopping you from specifying a base type. The above makes a call to [Enumerable.Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) with this signature:

```
IEnumerable<object> Concat(IEnumerable<object> first, IEnumerable<object> second)
```

Since both lists implement `IEnumerable<T>`, which is [covariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx), they can be passed as the `first` and `second` parameters without casting.

Comment: This is the best answer so far. It calls the same method as in my answer, but does so in a much more readable manner.

Answer (score 2):

Converting `List<string>` to `List<object>` is very simple

```
var yourList = new List<string>() {"hello");
List<object> a = yourList.ToList<object>();
```

You can do this with all of your lists and conact them using `AddRange`

Every object inherits from `object` so this approach is valid [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx)

Comment: That's not really a `cast`ing.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that .ToList<object>() creates a copy of the original data. Solutions that don't need to do this exist.

Answer (score 2):

`List<T>` is `IEnumerable<T>,` and these are covariant. So you can use:

```
var method2 = ((IEnumerable<object>)a).Concat((IEnumerable<object>)b);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var n = a.Cast<object>().Concat(b.Cast<object>()).ToArray();
```